# How to wait for user to close vim then run command in shell script

Tags: shell-script, zsh, vim

I'm currently trying to write a shell function for updating my .zshrc file. I currently have an alias that is as follows

```
alias zshrc="vim ~/.zshrc"
```

I was wondering if there is any way to write a function that would wait for me to close vim then run a command after vim has closed. For reference the command I would want to run is.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Just right a normal function, with the commands you want to run after vim included. The subsequent commands will not run until vim has been closed by default.

Comment: can zsh aliases not include a `;` or `&&`? `alias zshrc='vim ~/.zshrc; source ~/.zshrc'`?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, they can. Aliases are expanded before the command line is parsed. So they can contain anything you otherwise could type on the command line *because* they are replaced by their value *as if* you had typed it on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run one command after another, simply write them on separate lines, or with `;` after the first command. So change your alias to a function, and make it run `source ~/.zshrc` after `vim` has finished running.

```
function zshrc {
  vim ~/.zshrc
  source ~/.zshrc
}
```